# Conditioning two functions at a specific point

Tags: functions

I'm trying to create a condition for functions $f$ and $g$ at point $a$, without using any conditional function/ending in a conditional function

---

What I mean by saying "conditioning functions $f$ and $g$ at point $a$" is:

```
h(x) =
    if (x < a):
        return f(x)
    if (x >= a):
        return g(x)
```

In other words, "do $f$ until reaching $a$; whenever $a$ has been reached, do $g$"

---

An example of conditioning a simple function, i.e. $|x|$:

We all know that $|x|$ is a conditional function - but we can write it unconditionally as well: $\sqrt{x^2}$ - Neither $x^2$ nor $\sqrt{x}$ are conditional; but we used them together to write the conditional function, $|x|$

---

I tried to play with some functions like $max$, but I didn't find the answer in the end anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just create your favorite conditional function and combine those.
For example, consider the function $\mathbf{1}_{\geq a}$ where $\mathbf{1}_{\geq a}(x) = \begin{cases}1&\text{if }x\geq a\\0&\text{if }x<a\end{cases}$

Now just write $h(x) = \mathbf{1}_{\geq a}(x)\cdot g(x) + (1-\mathbf{1}_{\geq a}(x))\cdot f(x)$

But why do you not want to use a conditional function? Even "$\max$" is a conditional function.

Comment: We can write the function $max$ in a non-conditional form too, right? It acts like a conditional function, but we actually can write it using non-conditional functions, like the example that I said ($|x| = \sqrt{x^2}$). And also, what do you mean by $1 >= a(x)$?

Comment: The $\mathbf{1}_{\text{something}}$ is notation for a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function. You could define this as a translation of the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function (See the "Zero argument" section for edge cases).

Comment: If you want, you can define the Heaviside step function as the derivative of the absolute value function and then you are happy, but I still don't see what's wrong with a conditional

Comment: Yeah. We can define that even easier tho using the sign function, that is $|x|/x$, right?

Comment: $sgn(x) / 2 + 0.5$

Comment: Yes you _could_ do that indeed. The case $x=a$ might be tricky/imposible without just a normal simple conditional function (esp. when $f(a)\neq g(a)$), but indeed, $\mathbf{1}_{\geq a} = \frac12(\frac{|x-a|}{x-a}+1)$ for all $x\neq a$.